# Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.4, >= 2.1.0. rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After running `rails new demo` I get the following error:

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.4, >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My Ruby version is 1.9.3. I could update ruby but I'm worried that may create even more problems. Any suggestions?

More Information:

The Nokogiri gem is not listed in my Gemfile, if I run `gem list` it includes `nokogiri (1.6.8.1 x86-mingw32, 1.6.6.2 x86-mingw32, 1.6.1 x86-mingw32)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to downgrade the version of `nokogiri` to `~> 1.6.8`

change nokogiri version in `Gemfile`

```
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.8'
```

Dependency for nokogiri version `1.6.8` is `ruby >= 1.9.2` https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions/1.6.8

But it is changed for nokogiri version `1.7.1` to `ruby >= 2.1.0` https://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri/versions/1.7.1

Comment: I asked the question and I can't see why it's downvoted. Please explain.

Comment: Nokogiri wasn't included in my gem file but when I added the line as suggested by @Deepak Mahakale, everything works fine. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a dependency of some other gem you can check that in `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.4.1 on Windows, and I am not able to install the creek gem; I get the error mentioned by the original poster:  ERROR:  Error installing creek: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.4, >= 2.1.0.  When I tried to downgrade nokogiri with gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.8', I get a similar error:  ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.4, >= 1.9.2.